# Reading/Writing UTF-8 input

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, c++17

I realize that this question is not new, but many of the answers are rather old and I wonder if I missed something. I have spent the past days reading up on the topic, including the often referred

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- [Should you use std::string, std::u16string, or std::u32string?](https://ohadschn.gitlab.io/2014/11/should-you-use-stdstring-stdu16string-or-stdu32string/)
- [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

After this, I think I understand the difference between `code points` and encoding. However, the practical application still confuses me quite a lot. Here is my minimal example, though I would also like to read and write to CSV files, XML, HTML and others:

```
bool parseNamingPatternToVector(const std::string namingString,
                               std::vector<std::string>& outputVector) {
  bool foundCounterTag = false;
  if (namingString.length() > 0) {
    bool keywordStarted = false;
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (char &c : std::string(namingString)) {
      ss << c;
      if (c == '$') {
        if (keywordStarted) {
          keywordStarted = false;
          outputVector.push_back(ss.str());
          if (ss.str().compare("$counter$") == 0) {
            foundCounterTag = true;
          }
        } else {
          keywordStarted = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (foundCounterTag) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> sVector;
  bool parsingWorked = 
    parseNamingPatternToVector("begin$tag1$-あÖウめÜД-$tag2$end", sVector);
}
```

On the one hand I've read that `std::string` can handle UTF-8, on the other hand a frequent advice is to use `wchar_t`, which is then strongly rebuked in other articles (see above links). The program does run, but the output is wrong (of course).

So I'm still confused how I would convert the above code so that it works with the given string, let alone how to properly output the resulting vector into another file, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The size of `wchar_t` is platform dependant, 16 bits on MS-Windows and usually 32 bits on Linux. Use `std::string` for UTF-8 on all platforms.

Comment: Minimal example, not one single comment. Does not use `return foundCounterTag;` directly. In case you're not confident with all that (including coding): narrow your goal as in: first your program should work with ASCII, then with UTF-32 (or UTF-16)... and so on. UTF-8 is not the answer to everything, nor can it be asked everything.